# where does laravel can function for user object define?

Tags: php, laravel, class, oop, laravel-5

i am working on a laravel project .almost  i see in  each controller these line format :

```
!auth()->user()->can('something (differ from each controller to other one)')
```

but in my php editor it says method {can} not found for this object. so i try to found method can and not found it .even i edit __Call magic method to see if when can method is calling does magic function run but i know it never run for can function.so how it is possible to link function to object when it is not defined in class and its all mother class.and where  does can function locate?i search and i see laravel has some policy for authorize users but yet i don not know how can function link to user object without
define  in classes and even magic method does not run .and  how can i develope these type of function (for authorizing in laravel and change policy)

Comment: Its because your editor is confused. There's nothing wrong with the code itself.

Comment: Alternatively you can find the `can` method inside `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable.php` it's the full path for the trait to find `can` method. Here you will see that it basically uses the laravel service container

Comment: yes i found can method .thanks a lot .my php eidtor confused a bit .it is inside your  spoken path exactly .also i do not know about traits .so my effort to found can method was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`can` method is a part of `Authorizable` trait in `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access`

Look at your User model, you will found that model is extended from `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable`. and Authenticatable uses the above trait.

it's part of the core of laravel, you can read the documentation from [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#policy-methods)

Comment: i see laravel documentation and  traits in php . it was useful a lot.thanks.